# Apache geode behavior on low memory

Tags: apache, gemfire, geode

I'm evaluating geode for our product. I started with a simple test to check the behavior of geode on low-mem:
- launch a locator and a single server with initial-heap==max-heap==4GB, critical-heap-percentage=90%, eviction-heap-percentage=80%
- I see that gfsh passes in addition the following jvm params to server: -Xms4000m -Xmx4000m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60
- create a partitioned region
- run client which connects to locator and get the region as PROXY (i.e. no local cache)
- the client fills the server with elements until it gets ServerOperationException due to low memory (as expected)
- now, I remove all elements from the region and try run the client again - the client fails on the first put operation (although server is empty!)

My question is: why doesn't the GC collect removed items (I see on server status that currentHeapSize=3151MB, maximumHeapSize=3866)?. I'm expecting to be able to put data in the server if its empty...

Thanks.

Comment: Geode _will_ GC the removed items.  PS that you don't need critical/ eviction thresholds since you are not using overflow.  Are you sure that your remove operation actually removed the items?  How are you removing them? gfsh remove all? Client remove in a loop? Function removals?

Comment: Note that a client.removeAll must have keys (see [removeAll](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/basic_config/data_entries_custom_classes/managing_data_entries.html) )

Comment: I'm removing all keys using a client with region.removeAll(region.keySetOnServer()), after this command I'm checking the server using 'show metrics --member=server1' and see that the region is empty but still heap usage is very high

Comment: When not using the critical-heap-percentage the server just crashes when reaching high heap utilization. I also tried the --disable-exit-when-out-of-memory but with this flag the whole cluster is halt (the locator and server), gfsh loss connection to locator and I can't connect to it anymore

Comment: Assaf, good question then.  I suggest you ask on the geode dev list. You'll get a quick answer there.  http://geode.apache.org/community/

Comment: The server may be performing full GC during the halt. I think I hit the problem before, though we fixed it by changing a piece of code that causes memory leak.